# windows 7 and desktop icons

Tags: windows-7

how to put the real webpage icon on desktop of windows 7 with explorer it was simply shortcut on windows xp and in firefox i'd go to view/ page info/media...save the icon in a folder then left  click the icon on the desktop/properties and change the icon ...go and get it in the folder...i'm an icon nut.. i cover my desktop!

Answer (score 1):

You want to download the favicon.ico file. Most of them are stored in / directory of the website. For example Google is http://www.google.com/favicon.ico. You can save .ico files where ever works for you and then add it to your shortcut.

Comment: ALLRIGHT!!! YESSSSS! IT WORKS....AS YOU SAW IT WAS A SIMILAR WAY IN XP....JUST DIDIN'T WORK IN 7 ...A MILLION THANKS MAN!